Solving for a Specific Variable in an Underdetermined System of Linear Equations
I have an underdetermined system of linear equations of the form $Ax = b$, where:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{20} & a_{10} & a_{00} & 0 & 0  \\
0 & a_{21} & a_{11} & a_{01} & 0  \\
0 & 0 & a_{22} & a_{12} & a_{02} \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{0} \\
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix},\quad b = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{0} \\
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
I am interested in solving for $x_2$. Is it possible to get a unique solution for $x_2$ in this underdetermined system?
Additionally, suppose $x_0$ and $x_1$ are known to us. How would this affect the solution for $x_2$? I am interested in both the general solution where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are not known, and the specific solution where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are known.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Since $A$ is not full column rank, it has nontrivial nullspace, i.e., $\mathcal{N}(A) \neq \{0\}$. Hence, any vector in the affine set $\{x \ |\  x = \bar{x} + w, \ A\bar{x} = b,\ \bar{x}\in \mathcal{R}(A^T),\ \forall w\in\mathcal{N}(A)\}$ is a solution to your system. Here, $\bar{x}$ is the unique solution to the system in the domain of $A$, $\mathcal{R}(A^T)$.
If $a_{00}\neq 0$ and you know $(x_0, x_1)$, then from the first equation $a_{20}x_0 + a_{10}x_1+ a_{00}x_2 = b_0$, you can uniquely determine $x_2$.
